# EON chart populate from history

Tags: dashboard, pubnub, c3.js

I am using PubNub EON chart and I want to use the populate from history feature. However, when I set `history:true` the chart never populates with anything. When I set `history:false` then it works great. Here is the declaration:

```
<script>
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key: '------------------------------------',
        ssl: true
    });
    eon.chart({
        pubnub: pubnub,
        history: false,
        channel: 'tempTime',
        limit: 2880,
        ssl: true,
        debug: false,
        generate: {
            transition: {
                duration: 3
            },
            bindto: '#TimeSeries',
            point: {
                show: false
            },
            data: {
                x: 'x'
            },
            subchart: {
                show: true,
                tick: {
                        count: 12,
                        format: '%H:%M',
                        culling: {
                            max: 12 // the number of tick texts will be adjusted to less than this value
                        }
                    }
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: false
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        count: 24,
                        format: '%H:%M',
                        culling: {
                            max: 12 // the number of tick texts will be adjusted to less than this value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        transform: function(tempTime) {
            return {
                eon: {
                    'Ice Tank Outlet': tempTime.T0,
                    'Load Outlet': tempTime.T1,
                    'Ice RC to Water RC': tempTime.T4,
                    'Column Inlet': tempTime.T5,
                    'Condenser Dist.': tempTime.T6,
                    'Brine RC to Ice Tank': tempTime.T7,
                    'Ice Tank Inlet': tempTime.T8,
                    'Dist. Water': tempTime.T9,
                    'Chilled Water': tempTime.T11,
                    'Distillate': tempTime.T13,
                    'Chilled Coolant': tempTime.T16,
                    'RC Coolant': tempTime.T18,
                    'Warm Coolant': tempTime.T19,
                    'Brine RC to Column': tempTime.T20,
                    'Water RC to Column': tempTime.T21,
                    'Ambient': tempTime.T22
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please show the full eon.char object declaration code.

Comment: I added it above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does your API Key have `Storage and Playback` feature Enabled?  You can add this by logging into your account at https://admin.pubnub.com/

Comment: good grief. I am an idiot. On my honor I was sure I had selected that.

Comment: :) no worries. adding as official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable Storage & Playback add-on for your keys](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/644/how-do-i-enable-add-on-features-for-my-keys) in the [PubNub Admin Dashboard](https://admin.pubnub.com).

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. I do have a follow up question though. Currently when I load a new graph the populate from historical values is working! but it populates a somewhat mysterious number of points. It's hard for me to tell because my data is not consistent yet, but should it populate the full limit specified in the EON declaration? I have storage & playback set to 1 day, but it seems to be populating only a few hundred data points. Just wondering if there is some default value that can be overwritten.

Comment: Your Storage is set for 1 day retention so any messages older than 1 day. The `limit` param that you are setting tells EON to fetch messages from the channel up to that number of messages, and no more. But likely, you don't have that many. You may want to increase the Storage retention though.